# binding a Listbox in Silverlight RIA

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria

How to bind a Listbox in silverlight with DataContext option.I want to have a resource defined in the Usercontrol and want to use it as a static resource List box control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind the `ItemsSource`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyDataSource, Path=Data }">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDescription}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and define a `DataSource` called "MyDataSource":

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource x:Name="MyDataSource"...

</riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Comment: Ok its working but Can't we do it via DataContext and Resource defined up in the Visual Tree ?